# Git Bash for Windows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' using Python re to parse string

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-re

I am trying to use a pretrained CNN model for a project and some of the included code is having issues on my machine. Windows 10, git version 2.28.0.windows.1, Python 3.9.0

This code hails from https://github.com/zhoubolei/moments_models/tree/v2

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_file], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
# Search and parse 'Duration: 00:05:24.13,' from ffmpeg stderr.
re_duration = re.compile(r'Duration: (.*?)\.')
duration = re_duration.search(str(output[1])).groups()[0]
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gradx\PycharmProjects\final\moments_models\test_video.py", line 62, in <module>
    frames = extract_frames(args.video_file, args.num_segments)
  File "C:\Users\gradx\PycharmProjects\final\moments_models\utils.py", line 21, in extract_frames
    duration = re_duration.search(str(output[1])).groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Essentially the goal is to collect the run time of the input video file from some string Popen and re.complile() produce. This is not my code so I can't say why this method is used, but also can't suggest a different one. I've tried modifying the regular expression passed to re.compile() because I realize that could return None if nothing is found, but this hasn't helped.

Any support is appreciated.

Edit:
Turns out the issue was that ffmpeg was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main problem of your code** 
You are searching for a pattern and **trying to get its groups** even **before checking if the search returned something**.

```
# As the code is returning only the errors (stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# it is better to create a variable called error instead of output:
_, error = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_file], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()

# Lets check if the execution returned some error
if error:
   print(f"Omg some error occurred: {str(error)}")

# Get the duration returned by the error
# error are bytes, so we need to decode it
re_duration = re.search(r'Duration: (.*?)\.', error.decode())

# if the search by duration returned something
# then we are taking the group 1 (00:05:24)
if re_duration:
    re_duration = re_duration.group(1)
    print(re_duration)
    # 00:05:24
```

We are assuming that `Duration...` is being returned when some error happen, but if it is returned by the success output, then you must invert the variables and add a change to your subprocess:

```
# Changing variable to output and changing the return to stdout (successful return)
output, _ = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

Comment: Using this method to print the error I found that ffmpeg was missing and resolved this by installing it. Thank you.